# Calculating times in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that has multiple patient records for the same patients with the first two columns being their visit times, the next two columns being what stage of their disease they are in when they visited, and the next two columns corresponding with what treatment they are on. I want to calculate the amount of time each unique patient has been on the first treatment that gave them a response.

I was thinking I would try to write a for loop for each unique ID to go through two columns left to right and once it hits the first occurrence of a response it will flag the the start time and then continue to go through the dataset to make sure the patient is still on the same treatment and in response and to flag the end time and to take those times and subtract it to get the final response time. Some patients were still seeing a response however their treatments would change, so I want the for loop to break when it sees the treatment has changed.

I was able to write a function with a loop that records the start time of each patient by using a string check but I am not sure if that is the best way to go about it. If it is I would want to modify my code below to add in the checks.

Here is a reproducible example of how the data frame I am working with looks like.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Patient = c('Dave', 'Dave', 'Dave', "Angel", "Angel", "Angel", "Joe", "Joe", "Joe"),
  V1 = c('1', '150', '375', '1', '150', '375','1', '150', '375'),
  V2 = c('150', '375', '568','150', '375', '568','150', '375', '568'),
  R1 = c("Disease","Response","Response", "Disease","Disease", "Response","Disease", "Response", "Response"),
  R2 = c("Response", "Response", "Death", "Disease", "Response", "Death", "Response", "Response", "Response"),
  T1 = c("A","A", "B", "A","B","B", "A","A","C"),
  T2 = c("A", "B","B",  "B","B","B", "A","C","C" ))
```

```
target_string <- "Response"
strtTime <- function(id) {
  subset_df <- df[df$Patient == id, ]
  start <- NULL
  # Loop through rows in the subset dataframe
  for (i in 1:nrow(subset_df)) {
    # Check if the target string is in Column1 or Column2
    if (target_string %in% subset_df$R1[i] || target_string %in% subset_df$R2[i]) {
      # Record the result when the target string is found
      start <- subset_df$V2[i]
      break
    }
  }
  return(start)
}

pts = unique(df$Patient)
startTime <- lapply(pts, strtTime)
startTime_list <- setNames(startTime, pts)
startTime_list <- as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, startTime_list))
```

As for the expected output, for Dave his start time would be 150 and his end time would be 375 and then his extended response would be 225. For Angel start time would be 375 and end time would be 568 so the extended response would be 193. Lastly for Joe it would be the same as Dave's

Comment: I feel like I've asked this before ... why are your "time" columns `V1` and `V2` _strings_? (Did you not get any takers the first time you asked this question?)

Comment: Are `R1` and `R2` related to the `V1` and `V2`, respectively? For example, if the first "Response" is in `R2` is the start time the corresponding `V2` value?

Comment: @r2evans I randomly made up times that is how it is in my original data set so that's why they appear as strings.

Comment: @LMc yes! the visits, response, and treatments are all corresponding. V1, R1, T1 and V2, R2, T2 are all corresponding

Comment: Okay -- so why isn't the first response time for Angel 375 (`V2[5]`) and the last response time also 375 (`V2[6]`)?

Comment: because angel was technically still in response until death and could have died from other factors then the one my OG dataset highlights

Comment: I think my comment wasn't quite clear. If you're working with data and something in that data is supposed to be number-like ("time"), then I fully expect that your data would already be numbers before coming to SO. I prefer when questions have already conditioned the data appropriately based on expectations; for example numbers that are IDs should likely be `character`, `factor`, are at least `integer` (not `numeric`), and things that should be summed should be `numeric` or `integer`, things like that.

Comment: So then why isn't Dave in response until death? Why is he 150 until 375 and not until 568? Similarly, why isn't Joe in response until the last response at 568?

Comment: @LMc because both their treatments switched. I want the time they were in response on the first treatment the patient saw a response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution that works for your example data. We `filter()` to rows where `R1 == "Response"`. Then select only the first row for each patient and calculate the `time_to_response` by subtracting `V1` from `V2`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

res_df <- 
  df |> 
  filter(R1 == "Response") |> 
  slice_head(by = "Patient") |>
  mutate(time_to_response = as.numeric(V2) - as.numeric(V1))

res_df
#>   Patient  V1  V2       R1       R2 T1 T2 time_to_response
#> 1    Dave 150 375 Response Response  A  B              225
#> 2   Angel 375 568 Response    Death  B  B              193
#> 3     Joe 150 375 Response Response  A  C              225

res_df |> 
  select(Patient, time_to_response) |> 
  deframe()
#>  Dave Angel   Joe 
#>   225   193   225
```